# std_msgs::string compare in a callback cpp node

Tags: ros, c++, ros-melodic, callback, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to create a node with rosserial on Arduino. It should publish some sensor information and acts when I publish a command through a command topic.
I wrote a cpp node with a callback function:

```
void commandsCB (const std_msgs::String& commands)
{
  nh.loginfo("Reciving new message... \n");
  nh.loginfo(commands.data);
  nh.loginfo(scan.data);
  if (commands.data == scan.data)
  {
    scanning(pos, flag, minAngle, maxAngle, myservo, servoPos, pub_pos, scansNum, range_msg, pub_range);
    nh.loginfo("Scanning...");
  }
  if (commands.data == forward.data)
  {
    cart.forwardDrive();
    getRange(range_msg, pub_range);
    nh.loginfo("Driving forward...");
  }
  if (commands.data == backward.data)
  {
    cart.backwardDrive();
    getRange(range_msg, pub_range);
    nh.loginfo("Driving backward...");
  }
  if (commands.data == rightTurn.data)
  {
    cart.rightTurn();
    getRange(range_msg, pub_range);
    nh.loginfo("Turning right...");
  }
  if (commands.data == leftTurn.data)
  {
    cart.leftTurn();
    getRange(range_msg, pub_range);
    nh.loginfo("Turning left...");
  }
}

ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::String> sub_commands ("/commands", &commandsCB);
```

Where scan.data, forward.data etc all std_msgs::String types.

When I try this node and publish command, for example,

> scan

, I get from both

> nh.loginfo(commands.data)

and

> nh.loginfo(scan.data)

"scan", but it doesn't go into the if condition in the following lines in the callback.

I wonder if that's the right way to write this callback.

I'll appreciate any help,
Thanks in advance,
Iftach.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376372/std_msgs::string-compare-in-a-callback-cpp-node/) by [Iftahnaf](https://answers.ros.org/users/52515/iftahnaf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2021-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

your code compares the pointers of the strings. These are different, because those are two unique strings. If you want to compare the content of the string, use https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/
This would be in your code ...

```
if (commands.data.compare(scan.data) == 0)
{
   scanning(pos, flag, minAngle, maxAngle, myservo, servoPos, pub_pos, scansNum, range_msg, pub_range);
   nh.loginfo("Scanning...");
}
```

etc

---

Originally posted by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) with karma: 862 on 2021-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-17**:
And it's probably obvious, but this is not ROS-specific. It's C++.

**Comment by [Iftahnaf](https://answers.ros.org/users/52515/iftahnaf/) on 2021-04-17**:
Thanks for the answer.

I used std_msgs::String and not std::String, can I still access the *compare* method?

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2021-04-17**:
yeah, that is probably a little confusing: An object of `std_msgs::String` has one member, thats called `data` and is of type `std::String`. This is the same for all std_msgs types http://wiki.ros.org/std_msgs .
Thats why you have two additional `.data` in the answer above.

**Comment by [Iftahnaf](https://answers.ros.org/users/52515/iftahnaf/) on 2021-04-17**:
Great, It works after a bit of modification.

Thanks again for your help.